Coulomb's Law and General Relativity
How does General Relativity affect Coulomb's Law?
Let us imagine a non-rotating stellar black hole negatively charged to that exact point in which the force imparted to a distant electron is exactly zero. As the electron is really far away, we can model the force simply using Newton and Coulomb as
$$F = G \frac{m_\text{BH}m_e}{r^2} - k_e \frac{q_\text{BH}q_e}{r^2} = 0$$
If I bring the electron next to the event horizon of the black hole, just above it (outside – let's say a few metres away), will the two forces keep canceling each other out as it was when the electron was far away, or will some weird math make one force prevail over the other?
Conservation of energy suggests me that they will still balance each other out and the electron will hover above the event horizon.
Edit. For clarity: it is obvious that Newton's law will be different near the event horizon and I will have to introduce new terms to the equation, but the question is: will Coulomb's law be affected in the same way so that the two forces will keep canceling each other also near the event horizon?

You should write Newton's law as $F = R_s m_ec^2/2r^2$ for clarity, and include higher order terms in $(R_s/r)^2$ near the horizon.

The metric of the charged black hole is known, you know?

@JEB You are right. But if the two forces keep always balancing each other, it does not become so important that I express the $\frac{r}{R_{S}}$ ratio, does it?

@naturallyInconsistent If I ask it is because I am not able to understand Reissner–Nordström metric to the point of answering the question myself. Luckily the answer should be pretty straightforward: either they keep balancing each other or one of the two forces prevails.

The answer is clearly no the forces do not remain balanced because if they did the balanced particle could move freely in and out of the event horizon. Having said that, I do not know exactly how the EM force changes with $r$. It's an interesting question.

I would not be so sure. If you push the particle inside the event horizon you are effectively increasing its mass by adding kinetic energy, so it makes sense that it falls in and never comes back, with gravity prevailing. My question concerns a non-moving electron right outside the event horizon.

if you have enough acceleration from a force (like from a static coulomb force, as in your example, if strong enough), you can certainly avoid a particle to fall into the horizon.  However, remember that massless charges do not exist,  So the ration of charge to mass in a blackhole has a theoretical maximum, so the possible  distances from the BH horizon needs to taken into account. Otherwise the electric force, even outside the horizon, might not be enough to prevent the particle from falling in.

@PatoGalmarini I am always outside the event horizon. The only other condition is that we had previously measured that the two forces exactly canceled each other when the electron was very far away (e.g., several AU). If it is true, as you say, that the “distances from the BH horizon needs to taken into account”, then there are places outside the event horizon where one of the two forces prevails. But then you are already answering my question (i.e. the two forces do not always balance each other). If that is true, I would kindly ask you to elaborate in a separate answer.

What happens is, that electron's wave function inflates as it gets closer. So that electron is both above and below the horizon. ......   Oh yes, the forces cancel, according to me

@moonblink no, you don't need R_s/r. I just have an answer on this site where I do it, and it gives a sense of scale of when Newton breaks down.  I just copied it from a paper, it's tricky b/c it diverges. Also: I agree that interpreting metrics is not easy.

@JEB That's interesting. Could you please paste the link? And also a simple answer: do the two forces always balance each other or not?

idk. and I don't know how links work.
